# how can i find the derivative of $\frac{9e^{6x}}{7x-3}$?

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{9e^{6x}}{7x-3}$$

1. how do i find the derivative of $9e^{6x}$? I know how to apply the quotient rule after that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already figured it out, but for to elaborate for general cases if you have two functions $f(y)$ and $g(x)$ and you want to take the derivative of their composition, $f(g(x))$ you use the chain rule. 
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\cdot\frac{dg}{dx} $$

in your case $f(y) = 9e^y$ and $g(x)= 6x.$
Giving:

$$\frac{df}{dx}= 9e^{6x}\cdot g'(x)= 9e^{6x}\cdot6$$

Comment: this is wrong! It should be e^{6x} instead of $e^x$. I guess the mistake came from terseness of the formula. It should be: $\frac{df}{dx}|_{x} = \frac{df}{dg}|_{g(x)}\cdot \frac{dg}{dx}|_{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dx}(9e^{6x}) = 9\cdot6e^{6x} = 54e^{6x}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: so then it would be this -> ((54e^6x)(7x-3)-(9e^6x)(7))/((7x-2)^2) ?

Comment: Yes. (Except it should be all over (7x-**3**)^2, but that was just a typo I'm sure.

Comment: hah yeah it was my bad! thank you :)

Comment: @tilly Mind hitting that check next to my answer?